# How to change recylerview button Image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

When I Click download button. It's downloading. But, how to change button image when downloading once finished.

[image]

Comment: use a boolean variable in your model to check whether it is downloading or downloaded. If downloaded then make that boolean variable to true and call notifiyDataSetChanged() on your adapter class. if it is false, the show as downloading

Comment: As per @DemoMail Instead of `notifyDataSetChanged()` use `notifyItemChanged(int position)`

Comment: is it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `int downloadStatus;` variable in your model to hold information about download.

1 for available 
2 for downloading 
3 for download
so on...

When button is `Available` on click it to download change `downloadStatus` to 2 refresh the view using `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Once your download finish then  change `downloadStatus` to 3 refresh the view using `notifyDataSetChanged()`

For setting image use full condition otherwise it may show wrong image in button.

```
if(downloadStatus==1){
   //available image
}else if(downloadStatus==2){
   //downloading image
}else if(downloadStatus==3){
  //downloaded image
}
```

Replacing value code: suppose model is like this

```
class Model{
   String desc;
   int downloadStatus;

    public Model(String desc, int downloadStatus) {
        this.desc = desc;
        this.downloadStatus = downloadStatus;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public int getDownloadStatus() {
        return downloadStatus;
    }

    public void setDownloadStatus(int downloadStatus) {
        this.downloadStatus = downloadStatus;
    }

}
```

Replace:

```
    ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
    list.add(new Model("Firt Audio", 1));
    list.add(new Model("Second Audio", 1));
    list.add(new Model("Third Audio", 1));
    list.add(new Model("Fourth Audio", 1));

    //Replace Value 
    Model model = list.get(position);
    list.add(position, new Model(model.desc, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using some kind of background service or AsynchTask for downloading file or whatever.

Then on Completion of that task, you obviously got a trigger which indicates that task is done. So you can change the image at that time.